# zsh wait for jobs to complete

Tags: zsh, background-process

When I type the following in my terminal running zsh (each line is a command)

```
babel www/scripts6/lib/data.js > www/scripts/lib/data.js &
babel www/scripts6/lib/user.js > www/scripts/lib/user.js &
babel www/scripts6/lib/profile.js > www/scripts/lib/profile.js &
babel www/scripts6/lib/d3-and-svg.js > www/scripts/lib/d3-and-svg.js &
babel www/scripts6/main.js > www/scripts/main.js &
while [[ $(jobs) =~ 'babel' ]]; do echo 'moo'; done
```

it moos for about 3 seconds and then stops.  But when I put the same exact code in the file **moo.zsh** and then run it in my terminal with

```
zsh moo.zsh
```

it completes in less than 1 second and doesn't moo at all. Why did it happen?

Comment: moo moo moo moo

Comment: shells only tend to have job control turned on in interactive mode.

Comment: you should do the waiting with `wait`

Comment: @PSkocik make that an answer, it's correct. `wait` is the proper way to do this and will work both interactively and in a script.

Comment: @PSkocik Is there an easy way to turn job control on and off?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In non-interactive shell, you don't have full jobs control. When you start `jobs` in command substitution, it ran in a subshell. In this subshell, there's no jobs running, you got nothing.

In interactive shell, the [MONITOR was set](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Jobs-_0026-Signals.html#index-jobs), gave you full jobs control. In this case, `zsh` store all jobs in a table when you enter a subshell, and will use that job table if there's no jobs in subshell.

With `zsh` 4.3 and above, you can turn on job control in non-interactive shell by putting `-m` on shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh -m
```

or using `setopt`:

```
setopt monitor
: The rest of script goes here
```

A better way to check the job state can be:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
zmodload zsh/parameter

babel www/scripts6/lib/data.js > www/scripts/lib/data.js &
babel www/scripts6/lib/user.js > www/scripts/lib/user.js &
babel www/scripts6/lib/profile.js > www/scripts/lib/profile.js &
babel www/scripts6/lib/d3-and-svg.js > www/scripts/lib/d3-and-svg.js &
babel www/scripts6/main.js > www/scripts/main.js &

while (( ${#jobstates} )); do
  print "moo"
done
```

Anyway, you can wait for all child processes with builtin [wait](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-wait):

```
babel www/scripts6/lib/data.js > www/scripts/lib/data.js &
babel www/scripts6/lib/user.js > www/scripts/lib/user.js &
babel www/scripts6/lib/profile.js > www/scripts/lib/profile.js &
babel www/scripts6/lib/d3-and-svg.js > www/scripts/lib/d3-and-svg.js &
babel www/scripts6/main.js > www/scripts/main.js &
# Wait for all children
wait
echo END
```

Comment: Thank you, but the real question is about the absence of 'moo's.  The accepted answer must correctly account for such phenomenon.

Comment: @mareoraft: I made it more details.

Comment: A big MOO to you sir!!!